# How to remove an object from core data which is not present in another nsarray in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I had an application in which I need to remove elements from my core data object which is not present in an array of dictionary.

```
-(void)removeoldvalueswhichisnotpresentinnewone:(NSArray *)array{
    for(int j=0;j < [array count]; j++){
    NSString *pred = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"no !=\"%@\"",[array objectAtIndex:j]];
    NSArray *allRes = [self getObjectsOfType:@"Cr" withPredicate:pred];
         NSLog(@"%@",allRes);
    if ([allRes count] > 0) {
        @try {
            for(int i=0;i < [allRes count]; i++){
                [[self managedObjectContext] deleteObject:(Cr *)[allRes objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
            [self save];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception){
            //   NSLog(@"Del Warning: Caught  %@: %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
        }
    }   
    }
}
```

But it is not working fine.Can anybody points me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1. don't build predicates with NSString's `stringWithFormat`, use NSPredicate's `predicateWithFormat`.
2. Is `no` a number?  If so you should not be putting quotes around %@.
3. "NO" is a reserved word; try using a different attribute name.
4. Is your logic correct?  It will delete all the items that don't match the first object in the array (so only those matching first object will remain), then loop and delete all items that don't match the second object, etc (which probably deletes those left by the first pass through the loop).  You should only delete objects if they don't match *all* the objects in the array.  You could instead use an NOT IN predicate:

   ```
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (attribute IN %@)", array];
   ```

   You won't then need the outer loop.